# How do I upgrade my palace?

Tags: tropico-4

I have the "Palace Magnifique" task which requires me to purchase all palace upgrades. When I click on my palace, however, I see no upgrade button. How do I complete this task?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it turns out, I'm not supposed to upgrade the building. I'm supposed to purchase amenities for the palace. Any building with extra amenities has icons in its manage panel that can be found on the bottom of the box:

[image: Palace Upgrade Panel]

Simply clicking the icon purchases the upgrade, provided you meet the requirements and have the cash.

Comment: +1 for [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)